# decimal scale persisting in viewmodel

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel

I have a viewmodel which seems to be persisting the scale set in the database.  I have 3 updateable fields in SQL stored as a decimal(18,4) to represent money.
I wish to format the values in my viewmodel as 2 decimal places to make it look cleaner.

my viewmodel looks like this:

```
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}",ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
    [DisplayName("Value 1")]
    public decimal Value1 { get; set; }
```

my view looks like this:

```
<%:Html.EditorFor(m => m.Value1)%>
```

the values are given a default value of 0 so when I come to display the value in a text box, the value still retains the scale set in the database...

so my output looks like:

```
Value 1: 0.0000
Value 2: 0.0000
Value 3: 0.0000
```

if you know why this is happening or how I can resolve it in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want metadata such as the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute to be used you need the EditorFor/DisplayFor helpers in your views:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Value1) %>
```

or:

```
<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Value1) %>
```

instead of:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value1) %>
```

Comment: thanks for feedback - but i'm already using EditorFor (updated my question with my view)

Comment: @nologo, this works for me. Are you sure that there is not some custom editor template in which you have used a textbox?

Comment: still an issue.. if i set the database as 2decimal place. its fine.  using nullable decimals..